# Why are votes locked after some period of time?

Tags: discussion, policy, voting

When I try to remove a vote older than some (relatively brief) period of time I get this message:

> You last voted on this question
>
> X hours ago
>
> Your vote is now locked in
>
> unless this question is edited

I can understand why this feature exists I guess - to discourage frivolous gainvoting. But shouldn't there be some recourse for changing one's mind on the value of a contribution or simply making a mistake and wanting to take it back? Or is there some deeper reason for this feature's existence?

Comment: _Kevan shehigid..._.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voting is largely an anonymous activity so problems so *[tactical down-voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem)* — where a user down-votes another answer to temporarily elevate their own — caused the developers to add this vote lock-in.

But if you simply make a mistake, you *can* take it back. There's a window (5 minutes, I believe) where you can change your vote. After that, it's locked in. If the post is edited (improved), that *also* allows you to change your vote. And finally, if you really just want to change your mind, you are allowed to edit the post which will open up the vote window again.

That should cover all the legitimate use cases for changing your vote.

Comment: +1. But re "if you really just want to change your mind, you are allowed to edit the post": that's only for those with [the editing privilege](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq).